# Extremely disconnected or extremally disconnected?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, terminology

In the context of Banach space theory, what is the correct terminology: *extremally* disconnected or *extremely* disconnected. Looking through the internet I have met using both [extremely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808481/proof-that-ck-is-a-grothendieck-space-for-k-an-extremely-disconnected-comp) and [extremally](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128388) disconnected. Or is there  a difference between those two notions?

Comment: I think the correct word is "extremally" (which is not in standard English) and is indeed often mistakenly corrected to "extremely". Extremely would mean "very very", while "extremally" purports to mean, as far as I understand "in an extremal way".

Comment: In Gleason's paper *Projective topological spaces* (1958), it is called *extremally disconnected*.

Comment: The accepted terminology is extremally disconnected. As usual, the main criterion is "look at the wikipedia": https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space

Comment: or look at nlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extremally+disconnected+topological+space

Comment: or even the stacks project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08YH

Comment: A basically disconnected space is a completely regular space where the closure of every cozero set is open. Perhaps they choose the term 'extremally' so that it ends with the same four letters as 'basically'.

Comment: The reason "extremally" is not often found in dictionaries is that it is obtained from the adjective "extremal" by the standard method of forming an adverb with -ly.

Comment: See also pages 266/7 of [Algebraic characterizations of special Boolean rings](https://eudml.org/doc/212943) by M. H. Stone. Theorem 4.7 describes the Stone spaces of complete Boolean algebras and, in his words, exhibit the extreme of disconnectedness. That points to extremal.

Comment: N.B. that (unless your definition includes Hausdorff), a space may be both "extremally disconnected" and "hyperconnected": https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742443/extremally-disconnected-without-hausdorff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct word is **extremally** (which is not in standard English) and is indeed often mistakenly corrected to the more common "extremely" — possibly, in recent case, with the unfortunate help of automatic correctors. Extremely would mean "very very", while "extremally" purports to mean, as far as I understand "in an extremal way".

An MSN search *anywhere* = "extremally disconnected" vs "extremely disconnected" with "year $<$ 1963" yields 24 papers vs 1 paper (note that this mostly detects the spelling of the MSN review, although when misspelled it fitted the spelling of the paper in a few cases I checked). Without the year restriction (say, with year $<2021$, to fix things) it yields 600 papers vs 64 papers. In Google Scholar, the only few occurrences before 1950 are with "extremally disconnected" (I tried to open [a 1943 paper by Hewitt](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-43-01029-4) but instead noticed along the way that Duke Math J. still likes to get our money out of 80 years old papers).